# Quoting a path that contains spaces, in FreeBSD - why doesn't it always work?

Tags: shell, command-line, freebsd, quoting, whitespace

I have a directory on my FreeBSD server whose contents are created by Windows users over Samba. The filenames and paths within it sometimes contain spaces, as is common in the Windows world.

I just tried to delete some files in a subdir which had been duplicated.

- `rm -v "New folder (1)/*"` failed using both single+double quotes ("no such dir or file")
- `rm -v New\ folder\ \(1\)/*` succeeded

I thought that spaces in paths could be handled by putting the path within quotes. If I'm copy/pasting the path then I would find it easier to add quotes than to manually escape every space or other special character in it.

What do I need to do, to get the first example to work correctly?

Answer (score 3):

When you put the `*` in quotes then it's treated as a quoted character so it must be placed outside the quotes where it will be treated by the shell.

`rm -v "New folder (1)"/*`

Comment: Does that mean that `"my folder/"r*.fr?`, `"my fol"der/r*.fr?`, `"my"\ "folder/r"*.fr?` and `"my folder/r"*".fr"?` are all allowed and identical? Or are there important but non-obvious restrictions that apply to using wildcards this way??

Comment: @Stilez I made a correction. The slash, too, needs to be outside the quotes

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify though, what part(s) of a path+filename can/cannot be inside or outside the quotes, in this kind of use? For example, if the "/" must be outside quotes, what about `"my folder"/"my file"*`, or other cases where the filename also has spaces? And other more contrived examples such as `"my"\ "folder"/*"-2017 data.txt"`? (I'd look it up but no idea where to find info on it, or what to search under, for the details)

Comment: It makes no difference if `/` is inside or outside quotes.